# Best approach to merging Laravel and Wordpress in one project

Tags: wordpress, laravel, authentication, laravel-4, packagist

i am trying to merge Laravel and Wordpress together in one project.. 
the way i want it to work is, for Laravel to handle the Database Interactions and complex iterations going on on the site.. while Wordpress is used to handle the static contents, pages and all.. and using this approach, i want both of them to share a users table for login on both ends..

i saw this package on packagist jgrossi/corcel by Junior Grossi, and its doing a great job, getting the posts and all.. heres the tutorial  [working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together](http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/#using-wordpress-corcel),

but i'm yet to find one that actually binds both framework+cms to one authentication table seamlessly.. #anyideas..

i need ideas on this.. thanks.

Comment: With respect, I recommend against doing this. Consider what will happen when WordPress has an update and changes its schema? Or when your Laravel code writes an invalid record to WordPress's database in Laravel and hoses your WordPress site? This all sounds very complex and brittle.

Comment: good observation, what would you suggest is the best approach to such coz, i find it not nice having to have seperate usertables for both of them.. or maybe from the onstart would you suggest they both use seperate database...

Comment: WordPress has a rich ecosystem, and well documented ways to add plugins and other enhancements. If you want to use WordPress, I'd use WordPress's way of adding functionality rather than try to bolt on an additional framework.

Comment: the bad side to that is wordpress gets clogged at somepoint and you'd wish you seperated the functionality to a more versatile framework like laravel.. i'm currently working on a project using wordpress, and already i'm hoping i started it with laravel, because the plugins are making the system slow and all that .... though it works, eventually with time, i mite have to plug into certain parts of the application to retrive data and i'm trying to avoid any faults this early stage...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately all technical decisions come with such tradeoffs. :/